# Visual Studio Build Configuration Could not load file or assembly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I have an Asp.Net Web Application in Visual Studio 2013 and wish to add a new Build Configuration following the instructions here  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

I use Build=>Configuration Manager to create a new Build Configuration "InternalTest", alternativly  trying options to copy other configuration and not. This appears to run fine, but if I then try to run this build I get the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  ClubManager2

I have searched through the solution and there is no reference to version 5.2.2.0 of System.Web.Http

Does anyone have a suggestion to fix this?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Is there def no reference in the web.config?

Comment: There is a reference to System.Web.Http, but it's for the current version not 5.2.2.0

Comment: Have you checked that System.Web. Http is referenced?

Comment: As in is it in the project, yep. It's in the project, version 5.2.3.0

Comment: Web config also has <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you web.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Note the 5.2.2.0